# Удалить ссылки при определенном расширении экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
"<div class='news-img-area'><center><a href='/upload/" . $img . "' 
    data-rel='lightcase'><img src='/upload/" . $img . "'></a></center></div>";
```

Как можно сделать такое:

```
if ($(window).width() < 701) {
     удалить a href из кода указанного выше
     (чтобы показывалась только картинка без перехода по ссылке)
}
```

Comment: if ($(window).width() < 701) {
 $(".news-img-area a").removeAttr("href");
}

Comment: А вы не думали продублировать разметку - два контейнера рядом, в одном картинка+ссылка, в другом - только картинка, а css-правило `@media screen and (max-width: 700px)` управляет их видимостью - либо один, либо второй контейнер будет скрыт. Минус - чуть больше кода в разметке, плюс - это делает браузер, а не вы)

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```js
 if ($(window).width() < 701) {
     $('a').attr('href', '');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='news-img-area'>
  <center>
    <a href='/upload/" . $img . "' 
data-rel='lightcase'>
      <img src='/upload/" . $img . "'></a>
  </center>
  </div>
```

Или так:

```js
 if ($(window).width() < 701) {
     $('a').removeAttr('href');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='news-img-area'>
  <center>
    <a href='/upload/" . $img . "' 
data-rel='lightcase'>
      <img src='/upload/" . $img . "'></a>
  </center>
  </div>
```

Если удалить всю ссылку :

```js
 if ($(window).width() < 701) {
   var 
       wrap = $('.news-img-area'),
       link = wrap.find('a'),
       img = wrap.find('img');
   
   img.appendTo(wrap);
   link.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='news-img-area'>
  <center>
    <a href='/upload/" . $img . "' 
data-rel='lightcase'>
      <img src='/upload/" . $img . "'></a>
  </center>
  </div>
```

Comment: Я так понял надо не ссылку удалить, а весь тег `a`, оставив содержимое

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, добавила и такой вариант )))

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ($(window).width() < 701) {
  $('a').replaceWith($('a').html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='news-img-area'>
  <center>
    <a href='/upload/" . $img . "' data-rel='lightcase'>
      <img src='/upload/" . $img . "'>
    </a>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Класс, компактно!